What causes a dandelion leaf to be dark red?
Personally I find it quite attractive!

Taken near Toronto, Canada.

When subjected to severe arid conditions or stress, the leaf mutates to produce red pigments called anthocyanins which causes this.

I expect you are right about stress and anthocyanins, but are you sure its a Dandelion?

@davidgo sure they're dandelions. I assume you're not sure about identification because of it's non-serrated leaves. The plant is quite young, that's probably why it's leaves are that way. If you look through the centre of plant you'll spot some serrations.
